# Python requests module problem with proxies

Tags: python, python-requests

Its been a long time and i couldn't figure out whats the problem , i tried multiple methods to use proxies in requests , and the most correct one is the one in my code but it shows this error :

> **Max retries exceeded with url: http://toscrape.com/ (Caused by ProxyError ....**

```
import requests
proxies = {
 "http": "http://177.155.215.89:8080",
 "https": "http://177.155.215.89:8080",
}
r = requests.get("http://toscrape.com", proxies=proxies)
```

Comment: What happens if you set the proxies using environment variables before instantiating python (I am assuming *nix)? If that also does not work it would imply your proxies are not setup/referenced correctly.

Comment: You should show the full proxy error. My guess is that that proxy isn't working.

Comment: i tried the proxy with multiple proxy checkers , and they say the proxy is working